# How to check if an image is really an image?

Tags: php, image, security

I just wrote a BBCode class and users are able to put images by using:

```
[image] $image_link [/image]
```

I am currently worrying about people who could put code-injected image links.

How can I be sure the image is really an image and not a code-injected one?

Ps. Users can't upload files, just link from other websites.

Comment: `code-injected image links` --- wtf is this?

Comment: @zerk: a naiive user assuming that `<img src="nastyscript.js" />` would execute the js instead of trying to render it as an image.

Comment: @Marc B: does he? I was thinking it is some delusion that it is possible to inject some malicious code into image... :-S

Comment: @zerkms: not totally impossible. buffer overflows in things like zlib do let plain-jane gif/jpeg images contain malicious code which'd otherwise be totally useless elsewhere. However, rather unlikely these days.

Comment: What are you actually doing with the string between these tags?

Comment: Just convert it into <img src="$image_link">.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry nothing bad will happen with your current implementation.

If something is specified as `src` property value of `img` tag browser will try to show it as an image and will do nothing if it is impossible.

Comment: zerkms is correct. I will mention that devious users can still use the HTTP Location header to send the visitor's browser somewhere else (video count inflation), or do cookie injection. Some more professional websites will require a valid file extension (YouTube, which doesn't do much), or proxy the image themselves (GitHub, adds SSL), or validate the format.